# Adding a border around beamer poster

Tags: beamer, framed, beamerposter

I am trying to find a simple way to add a uniform border around a LaTeX poster, made in `beamer`, preferably in such a way that it is easy to modify the thickness.

Here is the first part of the preamble in my .tex file.

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
\usetheme{RJH}
\usepackage[orientation=landscape,size=a0,scale=1.41,debug]{beamerposter}
```

My current layout is that the entire poster is created in a single frame (i.e. all contained inside `\begin{frame}` and `\end{frame}`). So I am looking for a way to put a uniform, adjustable border around the edge of this frame.

It seems like this should be an easy thing, but I have only found directions for adding borders around frames when printing multiple slides on a page (e.g. `\pgfpagesuselayout{8 on 1}`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way with TikZ, requires two compilation passes:

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
\usetheme{RJH}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[orientation=landscape,size=a0,scale=1.41,debug]{beamerposter}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw [line width=1cm,blue] (current page.south east) rectangle (current page.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This just about works perfectly, except for some reason is creating a second blank page in the pdf output (with the same header and footer).

Comment: @GTFreiller Try placing the `tikzpicture` inside the `frame`.

Comment: That worked! I had to compile it twice to get the border the right size (just saying this for future users). Thanks for your help.

Comment: @GTFreiller Yes, forgot to mention that, sorry. Will add it to the answer as well.